# nginx redirect fails with chrome but works with other browsers

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, ubuntu, nginx

I am trying to redirect my confirmed email to the host(i am forcing http to redirect to https) but this works in all browser except chrome......initially i flush dns but this didn't fix it permanently...

i tried rewriting my nginx server,but am still getting email.mysite.com took too long to respond.but it works on all browser except chrome

```
 server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com email.mysite.com;
        return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name mysite.com email.mysite.com;
        #ssl on;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
            #ssl_certificate  /etc/letsencrypt/live/email.mysite.com/fullchain.p$
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com-0001/privkey.pe$
            #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/email.mysite.com/privkey.$
        return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.mysite.com;
        include snippets/pagespeed.conf;
        include snippets/optimizations.conf;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com.access.log rt_cache;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com.error.log;

        root /var/www/html/site/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
            add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";
        #ssl on;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com-0001/privkey.pem;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }


    }
```

the email.mysite.com should be loading in chrome since it loading in all browser

Comment: #1 You define multiple `server {}` blocks for the same domain. Don't do this. #2 you have setup a listener for `443` on both, the first one returns a `301` on SSL, which result in a never ending loop.

Comment: redirect mysite.com to www.mysite.com doesnt work for me without the second server block that was why both server both are separated...unless there is a better way to merge server block 2 and server block 3.....thanks